# I downloaded a model that already has a texture attached, why doesnt the texture appear on the model?

Tags: texturing

My previous question was closed and linked to something about cycles, as I've just started using blender I have no idea what that is. I want to know why a model that already has a full texture map still appears as grey.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're in *Solid view*, where textures don't appear.
Switch to *Material Preview* or *Render Preview* and your textures should be there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Im glad it was something simple, I've already done too much hairpulling!